# Outlook Email Signature - Images Not Showing Recipient Inbox

Tags: outlook, html-email, email, email-client

Our company runs Microsoft `Office 2013` and we are using exclaimer signature manager to manage our signatures.

We have just implemented a new configuration and there is a "bug on Outlook" (So I am told) which I have fixed mostly but hope someone here can give me a solution for Windows `8 / 8.1` as it's only working on our Windows 7 machines.

The bug stops the email's images appearing on the email recipients machine. The link & the steps below work for `win7` but not `win8`.

> **Key Outlook 2007 / 2010 / 2013: 
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail**
>
> **Value name; Send Pictures With Document**
>
> **Value: 0**

Can anyone be as good as to point me in the direction of a fix for this at all?

Thanks

Comment: What code do you use for attaching images? Be aware, the site is for developers. Ask non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about superuser.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are talking about the [Inline images may display as a Red X in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779191) case.

It doesn't matter what OS you are using. The windows registry key affects Outlook only. Try to restart Outlook, changes in the windows registry may take any effect only after restarting Outlook.

Comment: I am referring to that. Although, The change on this article and the link I posted on my initial comment have been implemented and it works. It works on Windows 7 but not on windows 8.1. I understand your response but that is not what I am finding ... any other suggestions?